# You configured HTTPS(443) on the standard HTTP(80) port

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ssl

In my apache error logs, I have bunch of ssl warnings saving `You configured HTTPS(443) on the standard HTTP(80) port!`

Here is my `site.ca.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.ca:80
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/site/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/site/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site.ca
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is my `site.ca-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName site.ca:80
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/site/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/site/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
ServerAlias site.ca
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ca/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ca/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Every thing works fine. I am not sure why this warning shows up every day in my apache log files, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, this is because you do not have any SSL configuration on the virtual host on port 443. You may need to enable "SSLEngine on" and provide certificate information. The warning indicates are serving regular HTTP traffic on what is usually an HTTPS port.

Comment: How can I enable it? Can you please point out where should I make the change in the conf.

Comment: I think this document can help you configure it: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Answer (score 1):

In these config files listed by the requester, there are some tweaks/corrections to be done:

- we don't need to have a **DocumentRoot** in the `site.ca.conf` because we will redirect **HTTP** to the **HTTPS** (`site.ca-le-ssl.conf`)
- the **ServerName** directive shouldn't have a port number, instead it should be in the VirtualHost level
- the ServerName and ServerAlias should be near to each other and there should be **[www.site.ca](http://www.site.ca)** as an Alias too in both files to handle the requests containing the www
- in `site.ca-le-ssl.conf` file there is a `ServerName site.ca:80` and **that's not correct** (there should be no port number)
- there must be a `SSLEngine on` in the `site.ca-le-ssl.conf`

I hope that help someone even this is an old question